# Move 3d object to mouse click position in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, transform, raycasting

I create a scene in unity. I add camera and 3d unity cube object to the scene. To move object to mouse click position, I add raycast and it works.

But I want to use my model. I have an `obj` and `mtl` file. I copy them to `Assets` folder. I use below code. The object moves but not exact my click position.

```
        Plane plane = new Plane(Camera.main.transform.forward, transform.position);
        pos = Input.mousePosition;
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(pos);
        float dist;
        if (plane.Raycast(ray, out dist))
        {
            Vector3 v = ray.GetPoint(dist);
            objectPos = v;
        }

        transform.position = objectPos;
```

Origin of model is not (0,0,0). I cut this object from a big 3d model.

I try to move to `(Screen.width/2, Screen.Height/2, 0.0f)` and result is below

**EDIT**
[image]

**EDIT 2**

I add `box collider` to object. But the collider position is not same as the object. 
[image]

Comment: Probably you should create images to display the differences between desired and actual behaviour.

Comment: @AntiHeadshot I add an image.

Comment: Are the plane and the object on the same Z level? You have a perspective camera so if the object is closer than the plane, the object will look offset to the outside, if the plane is closer then the object will look closer to the center then it should.

Comment: the object and plane same z level. Because I create plane at runtime using object's `transfrom.posiiton`

Answer (score 0):

You have to move the null point of the object or save a variable which is representing the vector by which it has to be moved and add it to the objectPos befor setting the `transform.position`

Comment: transform.position is not empty. It defines in unity and set default.

Comment: @zumma I didn't say that it is empty, you yust have to add an offset to it to accommodate the offset of the center of the mesh. Or put the mesh in a childobject of the collision object, so you can move it in the editor.